# Sorting an Array with .txt

Tags: java

Quick enquiry..

I have created an array and it will be populated by a scanner passing reading through information from a .txt file. The .txt file has a specific structure:

```
<job role> <years of experience> <name>
```

( this is an example ). This will be inputted by more than one person so there will be multiple of these in the text file. So, I now need to find a way to gather them into an array into an ordered structure. The order should be based on the first alphabetic letter of their job role. I was 
thinking about implementing a comparator would this be possible/efficient to do?

So my idea would be use a comparator somehow on specifically  and compare them will all other job role entries..

thanks and sorry if it's a brief or not very clear found it difficult describing the situation...

Comment: Post some code instead of describing it. Did you mean to link to an example input file? Can you just show a few line of the input file it here?

Comment: Read file, store data, define comparators as necessary, sort. Is this possible? Yes. Is it efficient? Not the question you need to be asking. Will we write this for you? No. Examples are easily found, JDK documentation is searchable and complete. Show us what you have and what specific problem you are encountering and tell us what you have tried to do to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accurately read in the text file, you would need a delimiter. A delimiter is a character that tells the computer that you are moving to the next data entry.

I recommend the following: for a new person, I recommend a new line *\n* as the delimiter. To tell the difference in the objects job, years, and name, I recommend using a comma, ",", as it does not appear that the the data set requires the use of that.

Once you have decided on a delimiter, I would recommend looking into the class **File, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream**. These classes are data streams that can read information from files saved on the computer.